# Get absolute mouse position from secondary thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, invoke

I have 2 threads:

1. Event listener
2. UI creator

Now I want that if an event occurs, the event listener asks the UI creator thread to change the UI.

This is my code until now:

```
    public delegate Point MyDelegate_get();
    public MyDelegate_get del_getxy;

    public delegate void MyDelegate_set(int x, int y );
    public MyDelegate_set del_setxy;

    public Point getXY()
    {
        Point absoluteScreenPos = PointToScreen((Mouse.GetPosition(this)));
        return absoluteScreenPos;
    }

    public void setXY(int x,int y )
    {
        SetCursorPos(x, y); 

    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         del_getxy = new MyDelegate_get(this.getXY);
         del_setxy = new MyDelegate_set(this.setXY);
    }



//Ui thread only launch Event listener

/***EVENT LISTENER*/

/*GET MOUSE POSITION*/
Point absoluteScreenPos =(Point) Dispatcher.Invoke(del_getxy);

/*MANIPULATE IT */
 int x = (int) absoluteScreenPos.X + delta_x;
 int y = (int) absoluteScreenPos.Y + delta_y;

 /*CHANGE MOUSE POSITION */
 Dispatcher.Invoke(del_setxy, new Object[] {x,y });
```

I don't know why, but I can't correctly get the absolute coordinate of the mouse if I am in a secondary thread. Can someone help me?
It does work if I have a single thread.

Comment: I do not see where you are running a secondary thread?  `Dispatcher.Invoke` will ensure code is run on the UI thread, not another thread.

Comment: I run a secondary thread in the Ui thread. All' the code after /***EVENT listerner*/ is executed in the event listener thread

Comment: How can we know what's wrong when you don't provide some of the code that could have the problem?

Comment: The problem shoul be in the function  public Point getXY() , it return wrong value

Comment: If this only *fails* when you have multiple threads, we need that information in order tell why...